# url rewrite path using htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'd like to rewrite the following path `https://example.org/app/my/index.php?param=/foo/bar/` to `https://example.org/app/my/foo/bar` and retrieve `$_GET['param']` in php using `.htaccess`. 

The parameter has to be modular so it can be any path. And I would like to keep the ability to add other parameter like `https://example.org/app/my/foo/bar/?id=XY`

The `.htaccess`-file is in `/app/my/`.

I already tried this, but it didn't worked out

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(app/my/[\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(app/my)/(.+)$ $1/index.php?param=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to avoid matching `app/my/index.php` or any other file inside that folder.

---

You may try this rule inside `app/my/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php?param=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: But it works only with `foo` not with e.g. `foo/bar/`

Comment: `.+` will match anything including `/`. May be you have some other conflicting rule. I suggest you to show your full .htaccess in question